# Strange DB Errors in celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I use celery with django, but not the django-celery module.

I get very strange database errors. They occur every time, but the vary. Here are some examples:

- ProgrammingError('no results to fetch',)
- TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
- IntegrityError: insert or update on table "myapp_mymodel" violates foreign key constraint "myapp_mymodel2_mymodel_id_fkey": DETAIL:  Key (mymodel_id)=(10082) is not present in table "myapp_mymodel".
- MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '""'. Reason: ''PicklingError("Can\'t pickle : 
  attribute lookup myapp.models.DoesNotExist failed",)''.

The code runs fine, if I call it direct (without celery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery starts the worker processes with fork(). If you do something in celeryconfig.py (or your tasks.py module) which uses the django database connection during import, you have to reload the database connection.

But the better solution is: Don't use database connection during importing (at module or class level).

You can use this little script to see if something deep down the import stack does use the database:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db.backends import BaseDatabaseWrapper
def raise_exception(self):
    raise Exception('Do not execute SQL during importing Python code!')

BaseDatabaseWrapper.cursor=raise_exception

import celeryconfig
for module in celeryconfig.CELERY_IMPORTS:
    __import__(module)
```